# checking value in datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have this datatable value with columns cell_1 and cell_2.

[image]

I want to check if the value already exist in datatable. I have tried using `dt.contain("textbox1.text")`, but it's error because in this datatable doesn't have primary key. Also I have tried using datafilter like this `string x = dt_aa.select("cell_1 = textbox1.text")`.

It works well, but when I try to input texbox1.text that doesn't have a value in the column `cell_1`. It gives me an error, because it doesn't exist. And my final approach is using this:

```
For Each dw As DataRow In dt_aa.Rows
    If dw("cell_1").ToString() = textbox1.text Then
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Cell_1 already exist !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Exit For
    End If

    If dw("cell_2").ToString() = textbox2.text Then
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Cell_2 already exist !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Is there anyway to simplify it? Because I need to check at least 4 columns with specific value. I am afraid that looping gonna take a while to process (CMIIW). I tried to use LINQ, but I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if a collection of data has a certain value, you can use `Any()` method in Linq.

**Linq method syntax (with lambda expression)**

```
Dim foundCell_1 = dt_aa.AsEnumerable.Any(Function (x) x.Field(Of String)("cell_1") = textBox1.Text)
If foundCell_1 Then
    XtraMessageBox.Show("Cell_1 already exist !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End If

If Not foundCell_1 Then
    Dim foundCell_2 = dt_aa.AsEnumerable.Any(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("cell_2") = textBox2.Text)
    If foundCell_2 Then
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Cell_2 already exist !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If
End If
```

**Linq query syntax**

```
Dim foundCell_1 = (From rows In dt_aa.AsEnumerable
                  Where rows.Field(Of String)("cell_1") = textBox1.Text).Any
If foundCell_1 Then
    XtraMessageBox.Show("Cell_1 already exist !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End If

If Not foundCell_1 Then
    Dim foundCell_2 = (From rows In dt_aa.AsEnumerable
                      Where rows.Field(Of String)("cell_2") = textBox2.Text).Any
    If foundCell_2 Then
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Cell_2 already exist !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If
End If
```

If you don't want to use Linq, you can use `Select()` method in `DataTable`.

```
Dim foundCell_1 = dt_aa.Select("cell_1 = '" & textBox1.Text & "'").Length > 0
If foundCell_1 Then
    XtraMessageBox.Show("Cell_1 already exist !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End If

If Not foundCell_1 Then
    Dim foundCell_2 = dt_aa.Select("cell_2 = '" & textBox2.Text & "'").Length > 0
    If foundCell_2 Then
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Cell_2 already exist !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If
End If
```

The Linq `Any()` method might perform faster because it returns true if an element matches the criteria so it doesn't need to check all the data.

**Note: I assume both cell_1 and cell_2 are string.**

Comment: if you mind, is that linq ? where can i learn it?. its still alien language for me :D

Comment: It's Linq. There are 2 ways of doing Linq, first is using method syntax (like what I did). Second is using query syntax (like SQL query).

Comment: See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/) if you want to learn Linq in VB.net.